# stmt.executeUpdate() returns java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01722: invalid number

Tags: java, oracle

I have FP_BIOMETRIC_DATA table in oracle whose primary key are CUST_NO and SERIAL_NO . The Blob column is FINGER_DATA . So I want to insert a record in this table . The code is as following :

```
public void saveFingerToDatabase(String username , String key , byte[] data)
    {
        try {
            connection =  DBConnectionHandler.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement("insert into FP_BIOMETRIC_DATA (CUST_NO,SERIAL_NO,FINGER_DATA,KEY_VALUE) values (?,?,?,?)");
            stmt.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(username));
            stmt.setInt(2, 1);
            stmt.setBytes(3, data);
            stmt.setString(4, key);
            stmt.executeUpdate();
            connection.commit();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SaveDataToDatabase.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        try {
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SaveDataToDatabase.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

But When I run this code it gives me the following error :

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01722: invalid number

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:331)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:288)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:743)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:213)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:952)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1160)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3285)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3368)
    at com.Futronic.WorkedEx.SaveDataToDatabase.saveFingerToDatabase(SaveDataToDatabase.java:43)
    at com.Futronic.WorkedEx.DbRecord.Save(DbRecord.java:184)
    at com.Futronic.WorkedEx.MainForm.OnEnrollmentComplete(MainForm.java:159)
    at com.futronic.SDKHelper.FutronicEnrollment.run(FutronicEnrollment.java:234)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I can't understand where is the error ? Please help me .

Comment: Please Show the dll and the values of "username", data, key

Comment: username is 19 , 
key is aT8wdC5PT/eAy75BMSOtqA== and  data  is [B@6d3538b5

Comment: The **DDL**, please. That is, the way the columns are defined. What are the types of the columns? Also, if the data is an array, you shouldn't just print it. The `toString` of an array is useless. Use `Arrays.toString()` instead.

Comment: can you run the script on sqlplus or any editor ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error code ORA-01722 states that you are converting string value to an int and SQL is throwing an error

Check that the (String) key  is declared as STRING or INTEGER

> **Description**
>
> When you encounter an ORA-01722 error, the following error message
>   will appear:
>
> ORA-01722: invalid number
>
> **Cause**
>
> You executed a SQL statement that tried to convert a string to a
>   number, but it was unsuccessful.
>
> **Resolution**
>
> The option(s) to resolve this Oracle error are:
>
> **Option #1**
>
> Only numeric fields or character fields that contain numeric values
>   can be used in arithmetic operations. Make sure that all expressions
>   evaluate to numbers.
>
> **Option #2**
>
> If you are adding or subtracting from dates, make sure that you
>   added/substracted a numeric value from the date.

https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora01722.php

Answer (score 2):

Show your table structure of `FP_BIOMETRIC_DATA`, check `'CUST_NO'` and `'SERIAL_NO'`, see their types are `varchar` or `number`.